# Кеширование в браузерах: nginx

Tags: nginx

Есть группа файлов, которые кеширует браузер. Эти файлы постоянно обновляются.

Файлы такие и находятся здесь:

```
site.ru/folder1/somename1.nocache.js
site.ru/folder2/somename2.nocache.js
site.ru/folder3/somename3.nocache.js
site.ru/folder4/somename4.nocache.js
site.ru/folder5/folder6/somename5.nocache.js
```

все они оканчиваются на .nocache.js

Как в nginx прописать запрет на кеширование? Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
location ~ \.nocache\.js$ {
  (root | alias | proxy_pass | ...)
  expires off;
}
```

Comment: три точки зачем? и что значит вся строка? спасибо

Comment: '...' значит что я предполагаю, что у вас хватит навыков выбрать куда добавить expires или самому написать проксирование/отдачу с диска.